# react http stream excel download

Tags: reactjs, download, stream

I am making an excel file download by receiving data when the server sends an http stream using the fetch method in react.

```
.then(response => {
  const reader = response.body.getReader();
  return new ReadableStream({

start(controller) {

function push() {
  reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {

  if (done) {
    controller.close();
  return;
}

controller.enqueue(value);
 push();
  }); 
}

 push();
}
});

})

.then(stream => {

const reader = stream.getReader();

const decoder = new TextDecoder();

let chunks = [];

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

function read() {

reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {

if (done) {

resolve(chunks.join(''));

return;

}

chunks.push(decoder.decode(value, { stream: true }));

read();

});

}

read();

});

})

.then(data => {

console.log(data);

const file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });

const link = document.createElement('a');

link.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);

console.log(file);

console.log( link.href );

link.download = 'data.xlsx';

document.body.appendChild(link);

link.click();

document.body.removeChild(link);

});
```

I'm doing the code above, but the file is damaged or an empty file keeps popping up.

It comes out like this, how do I fix it?

I use fetch method d.